# Why aren't Pthread Mutexes async-signal-safe?

Tags: linux, synchronization, pthreads, mutex

Pthread Mutexes are 'not asyn-signal-safe. What does this mean?

Answer (score 7):

It means you can't do anything involving mutexes from inside a signal handler.  (Technically, only for *asynchronous* signals, but all the *synchronous* signals are for things like "that pointer doesn't point to anything, I'm'a kill your process now" so it's moot.)

Comment: Any signal can be raised synchronously with `raise()`.

Comment: Sure, but have you ever seen a program that relies on being able to do that and then use non-async-signal-safe functions inside the signal handler?  It amounts to an expensive way to make a function call.

Comment: You can send a SIGSEGV to a thread/process via kill asynchronously. There is no way to find out about it. The 'si_trapno' in the siginfo_t field of the handler is not realiable.

Comment: @Lothar You should be able to distinguish reliably by checking `si_code`.  Some systems have much more elaborate taxonomies for `si_code` than others, but in general, it'll be `SI_USER` (or, if that constant is not `#define`d, zero) for a signal sent by `kill`, `SI_QUEUE` (if that constant is defined) for a signal set by `sigqueue`, and some other nonzero value for a signal generated by the kernel (which might of course be sync or async, depending on context).  But I'm at a loss to think of a situation where one would want to use a mutex inside a `SIGSEGV` handler, anyway.

Comment: I believe `SIGPIPE` will be synchronous, since it is raised in response to an attempt to perform a `read` (or `write`) operation on a pipe that has been emptied with the other end closed.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson Hmm, yes, I suppose that does qualify as a "synchronous" signal in the standard's sense.  The thing is, *any* signal can be delivered asynchronously because another process called `kill`, so it could be dangerous to do things in the signal handler anyway...

Comment: @Zack, that is true, any signal can be sent asynchronously.  However, sending signals a process doesn't expect is generally asking for trouble anyway, so it's not too surprising a process that is otherwise well-written might not handle that gracefully.  That said, I find the two most useful things to do with `SIGPIPE` are to either let it kill the process (since you're done with it) or catch it and clean up your side of the pipe, which is easy enough without anything fancy in the handler, so relying on `SIGPIPE` being synchronous isn't all that helpful.  I only mention it for completeness.